# Как добавить библиотеку в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Так и не понял, как добавить вручную Библиотеку PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet в Битрикс или любым другим способом ...

Answer (score 0):

На примере библиотеки PHPExcel:

1. Помещаю библиотеку в каталог `/local/modules/PHPExcel-1.8/`.
2. В нужном месте делаю вызов `require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/local/modules/PHPExcel-1.8/PHPExcel.php';`